# Sharing a java project (different IDEs)

Tags: java, eclipse, project, share, bluej

Me and my team were wondering how we could share our java project easily. I was thinking about using something like Google drive but it is quite tedious to download the files everytime any member wants to modify them. I know there exits easier ways to share a project for example using Eclipse but the problem is that we all work on either BlueJ or Eclipse. So is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read about "version control" ? Maybe something simple like "subversion" is good for you.

Comment: Bitbucket offers free private git repositories for up to 5 users.

Comment: Sharing is usually done through version control systems. If you use a build tool (maven, ant, gradle, sbt) that both supports, that would be the ideal.

Comment: For cross-IDE compatibilty either you can use build tools or simply initialize your repository inside 'src' folder not the project root

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)?

Developers use Subversion to maintain current and historical versions of files such as source code, web pages, and documentation. You can also add an eclipse plugin to update or checkout projects from a SVN server.

Or as of another solution, and making less effort in setting up a SVN server just use [github](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub).

[here](https://github.com/) is the link where you can signup in their website

Answer (score 3):

You can share the project with team using [**GIT**](http://git-scm.com/) or [**SVN**](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

**1)** It synchronize the project all the time when you(including your team) push or pull the code-changes to and from the server.

**2)** Easily compatible with eclipse.